# Write() starts halfway through

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-requests

I am new to python and I really don't understand why this is happening: when I run my code, the `lower()` is only applied to half (or less) of the text file. How I can fix this?

```
import glob, os, string, re

list_of_files = glob.glob("/Users/louis/Downloads/assignment/data2/**/*.txt")

for file_name in list_of_files:
    f = open(file_name, 'r+')
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Any reason you're using python for this and not a shell tool like `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably because you are reading and writing at the same time. And you need to return to the start of the file to write in place of the original content. Try this:

```
for file_name in list_of_files:
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
        content = f.read().lower() 
        f.seek(0, 0) # returns to the start of the file
        f.write(content)
```